# Search engine to check if a particular ip is web server

Tags: webserver, ip, search-engine

I have to automatically find web servers in certain ip range

It should not look like attack so I cannot use ping, curl, lynx. I cannot also use reverse dns.

The other approach is using search engine like google or bing. I can search by putting ip  in search box later I can check if address contains ip then I know that is web server.

But google not returns useful data. For example for ip 212.77.100.101 (which is web server) does not return useful results, any of them on results web page does not contain 212.77.100.101 on address (https://www.google.pl/search?q=212.77.100.101).

Is there any other solution to that problem or is there any search engine to use?

Answer (score 0):

This would really depend on a lot of factors. Your going to need some scripting heft to search through straight up google results for the information you want. Plus what do you mean by server? Just like a regular ole website server? You could probably utilize arin whois in some way to query ip addresses and any belonging to google, yahoo, etc etc you could identify as a LIKELY server IP address. If your looking to see if it's a server based on more technical information like OS, ports, etc etc there isn't much you'll likely find on google.

For instance an ARIN WHOIS of a google ip comes to this, http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-74-125-0-0-1/pft . Using your preference of language you could probably make the query to the web page and have it return the DOM or w/e to a variable and then look for the element that would have identifying information such as a google designation under name or something to that effect.

The best way to really tell, AFAIK, is to check ports and other techniques, which you cannot do by the sound of it. I'm not aware of a database you can access either that would have that information by IP address either...

What do you mean by server? That would help narrow down what your looking to accomplish. Just any IP serving up some sort of data? Or anything that comes back to a linux box or something?

More detail! :D

Comment: My task is to find representatives of autonomous system. By representative I mean web server.

It is good idea of using arin whois but on that page I do not see information telling me that this ip is web server

Comment: Yea. That's going to be a bit trickier because you will be needing technical information from each IP, which is generally only available during a probe or targeted search usually. Is it possible to port-scan through proxy?

Comment: It is not possible to scan through proxy. I think the solution is to use search engine but I don't know which one.

Comment: I will try my chances with online port scanner. Could you provide any which I can query up to 60

Comment: Hey, I just stumbled across this site and thought it might help you, https://dazzlepod.com/ip/ - I don't think it can do 60 at once, but it can scan IPs, if you could script a crawler you could harvest the scan results.

Comment: Thank you, useful tool. But finally i used revdns to get domain name and I asked for that domain Google. Which gives me good results